# How do I tell TypeScript that interface T is narrower than type U which has an index signature?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that validates a JSON response to make sure that it corresponds to a given shape.

Here are my types that define all possible JSON values – taken from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897#issuecomment-338650717

```
type AnyJson = boolean | number | string | null | JsonArray | JsonMap;
type JsonMap = { [key: string]: AnyJson };
type JsonArray = AnyJson[];
```

Now I have a function that does the validation given the object to validate and a mock object that has shape `T`.

```
function isValid<T extends AnyJson>(obj: AnyJson, shape: T): obj is T {
  // ... implementation
}
```

However when I try to call the function with an interface and a real object I get a type error under `Thing` in the type parameter

```
interface Response {
  Data: Thing[]; // Thing is an interface defined elsewhere
};

isValid<Response>(data, { Data: [] })
//      ^^^^^^^^
```

```
Type 'Response' does not satisfy the constraint 'AnyJson'.
  Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'JsonMap'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'Response'.
```

Curiously this doesn't happen when `Response` is a type instead of an interface, like

```
type Response = {
  Data: Thing[];
};
```

but then I do get the same errors but a level further down, on `Thing` itself, which is still an interface:

```
Type 'Response' does not satisfy the constraint 'AnyJson'.
  Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'JsonMap'.
    Property 'Data' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'Thing[]' is not assignable to type 'AnyJson'.
        Type 'Thing[]' is not assignable to type 'JsonArray'.
          Type 'Thing' is not assignable to type 'AnyJson'.
            Type 'Thing' is not assignable to type 'JsonMap'.
              Index signature is missing in type 'Thing'.
```

So my question is why does this expected narrowing not happen for interfaces but only for types?

Answer (score 4):

It's a known issue [(see microsoft/TypeScript#15300)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) that [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#implicit-index-signatures) are only inferred for object literals and for `type` aliases, and not for `interface` or `class` types.  It's [currently by design](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024); inferring implicit index signatures in the absence of [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) is not type safe.  For example, a value of type `Response` is not known to *only* have a `Data` property.  It may have a property incompatible with `AnyJson` (e.g., `interface FunkyResponse extends Response { otherProp: ()=>void }`)  So the compiler refuses to infer an implicit index signature there.  It's technically unsafe to do this for `type` aliases, too, but for whatever reason one is allowed and the other is not.  If you want to see this changed you might want to go to that issue and give it a  and/or describe your use case if you think it's compelling.  Actually it looks like [someone has mentioned this use case already](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-460226926).

---

So, until and unless that's addressed, what can we do?  Generally in these cases I find it's easier to represent the type I want as a [generic constraint](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) instead of as a concrete type.  Index signatures are instead replaced with mapped types.  The goal is to come up with a generic type alias `JsonConstraint<T>` such that a valid JSON type like `Response` will be assignable to `JsonConstraint<Response>`, but an invalid JSON type like `Date` will *not* be assignable to`JsonConstraint<Date>`.  Here's one way I might write it:

```
type JsonConstraint<T> = boolean | number | string | null | (
    T extends Function ? never :
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: JsonConstraint<T[K]> }
    : never
)
```

So `T extends JsonConstraint<T>` is true if `T` is one of the acceptable primitive types, false if `T` is a function, and otherwise it recurses down into the properties of `T` and checks each one.  This recursion should work for both objects and arrays, since [TypeScript 3.1 introduced mapped tuple/array types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

Now I'd like to write the function signature `isValid<T extends JsonConstraint<T>>(obj: AnyJson, shape: T): obj is AnyJson & T`, but that is an unacceptably circular constraint.  It happens sometimes.  One way to fix it is to change the signature to `isValid<T>(obj: AnyJson, shape: T & JsonConstraint<T>): obj is AnyJson & T`.  This will infer `T` from `shape`, and then check that `JsonConstraint<T>` is still assignable to `shape`.  If so, great.  If not, the error should be informative.

So here is `isValid()`:

```
function isValid<T>(obj: AnyJson, shape: T & JsonConstraint<T>): obj is typeof obj & T {
    return null!; // impl here
}
```

And now let's test it:

```
declare const data: AnyJson

declare const response: Response;
if (isValid(data, response)) {
    data.Data.length; // okay
};
```

So that works without error, as you wanted.  Let's see if it behaves as expected for other types.  We shouldn't be able to use `undefined` as a property type:

```
isValid(data, { undefinedProp: undefined }); // error! 
//            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Types of property 'undefinedProp' are incompatible
```

Or a function-valued property:

```
isValid(data, { deeply: { nested: { property: { func: () => 1 } } } }); // error!
// Types of property 'func' are incompatible.
```

Or a `Date` (which fails because it has all kinds of nonserializable methods):

```
isValid(data, new Date()); // error!
// Types of property 'toString' are incompatible.
```

And finally, we should be able to use `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, and array/objects of these without error:

```
isValid(data, {
    str: "",
    num: 1,
    boo: Math.random() < 0.5,
    nul: null,
    arr: [1, 2, 3],
    obj: { a: { b: ["a", true, null] } }
}); // no error
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApKB7YSDeSCwAUIUiUgC4CeMyAgsBWpkgLxIBG66ANhCFgD5JgAVzBsIAJySCoZCQEtgAc2lDhXLqsbAaEiSApaMwALIgYAbmKlK1VMbMwWOJAG0A1hAoAuJLIXKALq+dAzGSAC+VgSk5FTI2rr6hqyh2q6B0dYkimSSAGYIyAAqABaKKtjZsX5kwvn5vv4V0bER1bkFRUgAStAwmFDIVTE1JAAiIGQgvmUVGa2kUYTVtgnGAMKDciC5ADzFAHzOHNy8AmpikqrNyqoiGqoAFNWxxUgQAB55wAAmUEgAGLCYDwMjyJgAfiEEAAbtdvK9SO8vj9-kh0GwAFYQMFIaG4VwAaSQiiQngo6HySGKwXsmC2wH8u2AZAOxMCx3aozGvmAcMk1QAlCseUh8iCwRCsPIoAA1EBceS-A6HJ6YrEhejaAA0flK5ggsyQADJ6cBGcz9kchb4NaSAWsqRjsaaaTgkSQJBA6hIsA8uABCRYkbnVX64rggb1IeDbJC-KYzJBpYyi2IR+BRmNxplkJDe2CDI29frFkOk6lPWUKpW-J6J6Z6wsDJkQIVCj1ijNJgB0k2mvZ4yjIpQsSAA9BOMe4DPgxcsiGKa4rlQ2k3rcCCI-lFBBfgAFCToGC+bcQXf836RIXjqcfPToCSB+exe9jGoAP2-P9-f--AHVPexTxACzowMe1ASJQSAAOTnpe+5HiesFINGyCKHGYBwOCbA8OmpArnW65Ni4EYQDAXA+C4-KyPuvi4BBJ6SJQDHipKvhPJ2zDHAAjJEAkRDed7TpIx7PkB04gdQYHUkxUEwbBEqgqh6GkqC6DYVM8h4RAvYETk8qrvWjYgHq-IAO5IAOEBcbek6iY+ElisBoEYnJkEsYYsFkOgADKcgVKpMaYZpOE6Tw+lLrERFrqZm6erUEi+AARClOqJSIYC+LxGXdqQpy+GYo69vofyaVxSB7EgAAMvYAKx5R+ahcHy6hcE1H7Rslbi5UgABMeoAMyBJ1Ywamxya4GwviuClIDpeQEjCBA5ntYEgljcJDlCOgD7iaKh1LkdJ3HWdsRrCmzi4J8Z5-Bee7XouF3xEgABCzjaJaOz7DQhwdEZdZ7Ddd07o9kRqgGgZrRogYigQERAA)